# Running Stored Procedures Hangs Sometimes

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, datagridview, parameters

I have a stored procedures in SQL Server which is called from front-end form in VB. Here is an example of what I am doing:

It runs 1st stored procedure, which runs fine, and populates a datagridview, ie.

[image: DataGridView]

Then when you click on a row it runs a 2nd stored procedure using some of the cell values as parameters. This is where sometimes it's hanging. 
Trying to figure out what's causing this. Some of the stored procedures have only 2 parameters I don't think that makes a difference.

Comment: Great.  What is your question?

Comment: Impossible to answer unless you show the code. You may have an infinite loop in there or your stored procedure may be too slow. At least, use `async/await` in the event handler and load the data using the asynchronous versions of whatever library you use to load the data. This won't run faster, but at least the UI won't hang

Comment: The stored procedures run fine in SQL Server, in VB.net is where it's slow or hangs. I was going to post the code in a bit, I am just looking it over again. Thanks.

Comment: step through one line at a time, and determine where it hangs...

Comment: OK let's say the results are: http://i.imgur.com/s3hseJe.jpg

It seems to hang when the 2nd stored procedure is populating a number of results to the datagridview. Honda Civic has 2 total, no hang where as Kia Soul has 37 total and causes it to hang. Hmmm.....